# How do I get the placeholder to display when Angular Material Datepicker is filled in?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am using the Angular Material Datepicker functionality. It is working fine other than the placeholder. In the docs, the placeholder becomes a small label when the input is filled in with a date. Mine is disappearing.

I have tried changing css to get it to work and even tried using a mat-label with no success.

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="payBeginningDate" formControlName="payBeginningDate" id="payBeginningDate" placeholder="Beginning Date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="payBeginningDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #payBeginningDate></mat-datepicker>
```

I simply want the placeholder of "Beginning Date" to shrink over the date field like a label as it does in the docs.

Comment: Your label actually disappears totally? Even before making any changes to the CSS?

Comment: Yes...once I start filing in the date, it disappears instead of animating above it like a "normal" mat-input field.

Answer (score 2):

A mat-label above the input inside mat-form-field works for me, but it might be because I'm using outline appearance.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Beginning Date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="payBeginningDate" 
        formControlName="payBeginningDate" id="payBeginningDate" placeholder="Beginning Date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="payBeginningDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #payBeginningDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a problem I had when migrating from Angular 14 to 16... You can remove totally the placeholder by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code;

import below CSS file in your code;

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

    <mat-form-field>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="payBeginningDate" formControlName="payBeginningDate" id="payBeginningDate" placeholder="Beginning Date">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="payBeginningDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #payBeginningDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: import indigo-pink css file in your app.css    @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

Comment: I already have this in my styles.css...
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

Comment: @ClayHess I have just updated my code try again. you need to add <mat-form-field> tag for your input

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I already had those wrapped around my code. I just didn't include them in my code snippet.